# TYPO3 - typoscript: exclude certain page ids from adding a class via ATagParams?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Is it possible to exclude adding a class 'myclass' via ATagParams for certain pages or rootlines? (I still want them to appear in the nav as a link ...)

```
lib.navigation.main {

10 = HMENU
10 {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> | </ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            subst_elementUid = 1
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            ATagParams = class="myclass"
            allStdWrap.insertData = 1
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li> 
        }
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is since ATagParams of TMENU got "stdWrap"-properties. If you see in the TSref docs that anything got stdWrap-properties, all of those functions are available there for you: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html

To exclude some pages you may try something like this with ATagParams:

```
ATagParams = class="myclass"
ATagParams {
  # The pageIds you don't want to get this class
  if.value = 11, 22, 33
  if.isInList.field = uid
  if.negate = 1
}
```

Something like that... I did not test it.

Answer (score 2):

Should be reduced to:

```
ATagParams = class="myclass"
ATagParams {
  if.value = 11, 22, 33
  if.isInList.field = uid
  if.negate = 1
}
```